# How to calculate this Multiple integral？

Tags: integration

How to calculate this Multiple integral

$$\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R}x^2e^{-y^2}\sin(y)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$

without other condition？

Answer (score 2):

Your integral is undefined since

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^{2}{\rm d}x=\infty$$

diverges.

Comment: This is not correct according to wolfram alpha, it says the integral evaluates to $0$

Comment: Probably because $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-y^{2}}\sin\left(y\right){\rm d}y=0$$ since this function is odd. Still, you should be able to switch between integrals for the double integral to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

If the region is $\mathbb{R}$, then we have:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^2e^{-y^2}\sin(y)\text{ dy dx}=\left(\int_\mathbb{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}\sin(y)\text{ dy}\right)\left(\int_{\mathbb{-\infty}}^{\infty}x^2\text{ dx}\right)$$

Now, evaluate each of the integrals separately.

First we note that $$\left[\dfrac{x^3}{3}\right]^\infty_{-\infty}=\infty+\infty=\infty\text{ (approaches a large number)}$$

Note also that the function $e^{-y^2}\sin(y)$ is **odd**, which means that $\int^{a}_{-a}e^{-y^2}\sin(y)\text{ dy} = 0$. Therefore, we have the following:

$$0\cdot \infty\to0$$

This is not undefined since the limit "approaches" a very large number, whereas the limit approaches a very "small" number, therefore the overall limit is just $0$

Comment: This is most definitely ill defined. A limit of the form $0\cdot \infty$ can approach *any* real number in general. If you want to show it approaches $0$ we need to use some sort of asymptotic bound. I would recommend letting the integrals be from $-R$ to $R$ and then evaluating both, multiply the result, and take the limit as $R \to \infty$. Since the left integral will always yield zero for any choice of $R$ while the right integral will be nonzero, we have that the Principle Value is zero.

Comment: I agree its not the best way, but from my understanding an integral is simply a limit, and since we can split this integral, we have a very big number times a very small number, which is a very small number, and which tends to go to $0$

Comment: the problem is that your logic doesn't always hold. By your logic, $\lim_{x \to \infty} x = (\lim_{x \to \infty} 1/x) (\lim_{x \to \infty} x^2) = 0\cdot \infty \to 0$ which is false.

Comment: Not entirely the same. Notice how in the example we are integrating with respect to two different variables, which **have nothing to do with eachother**. Hence we can split up the integral. Clearly in your example we can simplify to just $x$. There is no simplification in the integration

Comment: sure, but that isn't quite relevant here. Choose to make the left limit with respect to y and the right limit with respect to z if you want. Then we have two variables, one approaching zero and the other approaching infinity. The problem is that we have to know at what RATE they approach in order to calculate asymptotics, just as we do with these integrals. At the end of the day, indeterminate limits are just that - indeterminate. You need something like asymptotics, LHopitals Rule, etc to get a valid finite answer out of **any** indeterminate limit.